# Google Analytics with PHP FRAMEWORKS

Tags: php, laravel, google-analytics

At my company we tend to put Google Analytics on our sites to gather some basic statistics like page views, bounce rates and others.

Recently it has been decided that Analytics should be further harnessed to gain insight into how our websites fair in terms of hitting particular targets.

Now, when using PHP frameworks such as Laravel, much of the architecture out of the box is based on server side code.

**One example: submitting a form**

User submits a form and you track a successful form submission with Analytics, but if the form submits and then the server side validation fails, this is actually a failure.

**My question:**

How do you effectively use Google Analytics with a server side framework? If you're not using AJAX there isn't even a callback for the JavaScript code to use.

So, the only way you could track a success in most cases would be to have a page load event for a thank you page or something similar.

Further to this, if all your validation is server side, would you not end up having to nest any GA events with PHP code anyway?

Comment: Things like successful/failed form submissions shouldn't be pageview-based. You'd want to fire off an [analytics event](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events). You'd probably trigger it with Laravel's [session flash](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#flash-data) so a page refresh won't re-send the event.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this Laravel Package to send custom events to Google Analytics in PHP:

https://github.com/irazasyed/laravel-gamp